# JQuery function is not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

Below is my HTML code to handle, on click of `id`, it has to call javascript function `viewLineActionURL` and then to controller. Both of the alerts are coming, but still it is not calling the controller `modifyLine` method.

```
<script>
var viewLineActionURL;
$(document).ready(function() {
viewLineActionURL = function(obj) {
        alert('view*' + obj + '*');     
        $("#formname").attr("action",obj);   // To Controller
        alert('false..');  
    }; 
});     
</script>   


<table class="tg" id="pResultsjoin">
        <thead align="left">
            <tr>
                <th class="tg"><input type="checkbox" id="all" disabled="disabled" onclick="toggle(this);" /></th>
                <th class="tg">Person Id#</th>
                 <th class="tg">Age</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="left">
            <tr th:each="map : ${list}">
                <td class="tg bg"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" name="check" th:value="${map['PID']}" /></td>
                <td class="tg bg em" th:id="${map['PID']}"  th:name="${map['PID']}" th:text="${map['PID']}" th:onclick="'javascript:viewLineActionURL(\'' + @{/LineController/modifyLine} + '\')'" ></td> 
                <td class="tg bg" th:text="${map['AGE']}"></td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

But I have this below similar code working:

Button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Modify" class="btn btn-primary" id="modifyLine" th:onclick="'javascript:modifyLineActionURL(\'' + @{/LineController/modifyLine} + '\')'" />
```

Javascript:

```
modifyLineActionURL = function(obj) { 
        if ($('.checkboxclass:checked').length == 1) {  
            $("#formname").attr("action",obj);
        } else if ($('.checkboxclass:checked').length > 1) { 
            alert('Please select only one quotation line');
        } else { 
            alert('Please select a quotation line');
        }
    };
```

Can anyone help on this issue

Comment: What do you mean by *"but still it is not calling the controller method."*? First of all, there is no element with ID `formname` and second of all, `attr` simply changes the attribute of the element. It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Why do you expect `$("#formname").attr("action", obj);` to call the controller?

Comment: `$("#formname").attr("action",obj); ` This line has to make a call to controller. But it is not behaving in this way.

Comment: @Cymen Yes. modifyLine method of LineController

Comment: You seem to have the wrong expectation of `.attr`. Again, all it does is change an elements attribute. I suggest to read its documentation: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @Java_User This is what jQuery .attr is: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thankyou very much. I have edited the question with the code snippet similar to the older one WHICH is working. ` $("#formname").attr("action",obj);` calls the controller.

Comment: The difference is the code which is not working is handled on click of `<td class="tg bg em" th:id="${map['PID']}"  th:name="${map['PID']}" th:text="${map['PID']}" th:onclick="'javascript:viewLineActionURL(\'' + @{/LineController/modifyLine} + '\')'" ></td> ` . The code which is working gets handled on click of `<input type="submit" value="Modify" class="btn btn-primary" id="modifyLine" th:onclick="'javascript:modifyLineActionURL(\'' + @{/LineController/modifyLine} + '\')'" />`